# Firing ItemListener when JComboBox index is set programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I'm new to Java Swing. Please help me on how to achieve below requirement.

On click of a button I have to open a dialog box. My dialog box has 2 `JComboBox`. I have written an `ItemListner` on `JComboBox1` to populate values in `JComboBox2`.

What I need now is on load of the dialog I wanna manually set an Item in `JComboBox1` and the `ItemListner` should fire for `JComboBox2`.

The below code I'm using in the method that opens the dialog. But the `ItemListener` is not firing

```
JComboBox jComboBox1;

populateJComboBox(); // Method to populate JComboBox1

jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(0);

ItemListener il = new ItemListener() {
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    populateJComboBOx2();
  }
};
jComboBox1.addItemListener(il);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) See also the comment left when [editing the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38522124/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

instead of an `ItemListener` implement an `ActionListener`

```
public class ComboBoxDemo implements ActionListener {
...
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(this) {
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getSource().equals(jComboBox1)){
         populateJComboBox2();
     }
}
}
```

[Java Docs Link for more Information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                if (e.getSource().equals(jComboBox1)) {
                    populateJComboBox2();
                }
            }
        });                                 - Tried this but not working. I'm not sure how to format code in a comment. So sorry for not being able to format

Comment: 1. do you revalidate and repaint the Panel in your populateJComboBox2?
2. add some Output into the ActionListener Methode so you can confirm if the Event is triggerd or